# An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects". com/android/io/StreamException

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, adt, m2e

I'm pretty new to Android development, so I decided starting with simple hello world application" my steps were:

1. in command line: "mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=android-quickstart -DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.android.archetypes -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.7 -DgroupId=com.agibalov -DartifactId=my-app"
   After success went to eclipse
2. File->Import->Existing Maven Project->Selected project i've just created with maven
   and after clicking "Finish" i got error "An internal error occurred during: "Importing Maven projects".  com/android/io/StreamException"

---

- Maven version 3.0.3
- Java version 1.7.0_05
- eclipse Juno or Helios
- installed ADT plugin for the Eclipse IDE
- Android configurator for m2e

Please let me know if more details are required for preventing this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with ADT 20.0.0+ and the Android Connector for Maven (m2e-android) plugin. The new 0.4.2 release fixes this issue was released today, please run an Eclipse update (Help -> Check for Updates) and let me know if this resolves your problems.